# Graphics3D with explicit ViewAngle inside Manipulate disappears for a moment when starting rotation

Tags: graphics, manipulate

Given the following:

```
Manipulate[
    ContourPlot3D[
        x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 + 3 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) == 3 c,
        {x, -3, 3},
        {y, -3, 3},
        {z, -3, 3},
        ImageSize -> 500,
        ViewAngle -> 30 \[Degree]
        ],
    {c, 0, 2}
    ]
```

Almost every time I start to rotate the resulting graphic, it disappears for just a moment. ([Example WebM](https://gfycat.com/DecimalPlushGecko))

With `ViewAngle` set to `Automatic` this issue mysteriously disappears.

What might be causing this and how can I prevent it? Or, is there another way to achieve a fixed `ViewAngle` that needn't include all objects?

*Edit: I'm running v10.1*

Comment: I can confirm this problem (V10 with windows)

Comment: Works fine in Win10 V11.1.1

Comment: No problem on 11.1.1.0 on OSX.